# Where is the error in this proof :

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, special-functions

Prove that:
$$\frac {2\Gamma'(2z)}{\Gamma(2z)}-\frac {\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}-\frac {\Gamma \prime(z+\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(z+\frac{1}{2})} =2 \log 2$$
But I obtain this equal zero.

My proof:
From Weierstrass definition of Gamma we have 
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}=z.e^{\gamma z}.\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}[ (1+\frac{z}{n}).e^{\frac{-z}{n}} ] $$
$$ -log( \Gamma(z))=log (z)+{\gamma z}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[ log((1+\frac{z}{n}))-{\frac{z}{n}} ] $$

$$ log( \Gamma(z))=-log (z)-{\gamma z}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[ log((1+\frac{z}{n}))-{\frac{z}{n}} ] $$

$$\frac {\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)} =-\frac{1}{z} -{\gamma }-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[ ((\frac{1}{z+n}))-{\frac{1}{n}} ]$$

This implies >> 
$$\frac {2\Gamma'(2z)}{\Gamma(2z)} - \frac {\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)} - \frac {\Gamma'(z+\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(z+\frac{1}{2})}$$
$$= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{z+\frac{1}{2}+n} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z+n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{2z+n} $$

$$= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{z+\frac{1}{2}+n} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{z+n+1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2}{2z+n+1}$$ $$=  
(\frac{1}{z+\frac{1}{2}})+(\frac{1}{z+1})-(\frac{2}{2z+1})+(\frac{1}{z+\frac{3}{2}})+(\frac{1}{z+2})-(\frac{2}{2z+2})+(\frac{1}{z+\frac{5}{2}})+(\frac{1}{z+3})-(\frac{2}{2z+3})+... $$
$$ = (\frac{1}{z+\frac{1}{2}})+(\frac{1}{z+1})-(\frac{1}{z+\frac{1}{2}})+(\frac{1}{z+\frac{3}{2}})+(\frac{1}{z+2})-(\frac{1}{z+1})+(\frac{1}{z+\frac{5}{2}})+(\frac{1}{z+3})-(\frac{1}{z+\frac{3}{2}})+...=0  $$

Where is the error ?

Comment: Hmm, aren't these divergent series?

Comment: @MPW all of them, yes.

Comment: Then you can't manipulate them this way. This is akin  to saying something like $\infty -\infty =0$. Do you see anything wrong with this? You simply can't treat infinite series as sums, because they aren't sums. They are limits, not sums of infinitely many terms. It is incorrect to say $\lim S_n + \lim T_n = \lim (S_n + T_n)$ unless you can justify that all three limits exist and satisfy this equation. You can't just push symbols around. In addition, I'm not sure why you think these series represent the expressions on the line above--I've not seen that before, is it true ?

Comment: yes,it,s true 
this is from Gamma special function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rewrite your equation :
$$\tag{1}\frac {2\Gamma'(2z)}{\Gamma(2z)}-\frac {\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}-\frac {\Gamma \prime(z+\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(z+\frac{1}{2})} =2 \log 2$$
as
$$\left[\log\Gamma(2z)-\log\Gamma(z)-\log \Gamma\left(z+\frac 12\right)\right]'=2 \log 2$$
or 
$$\tag{2}\left[\log\frac{\Gamma(2z)}{\Gamma(z)\,\Gamma\left(z+\frac 12\right)}\right]'=2 \log 2$$
which is easily deduced from the ["duplication formula"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) $\;\displaystyle \Gamma(z)\,\Gamma\left(z+\frac 12\right)=2^{1-2z}\sqrt{\pi}\;\Gamma(2z)$.

---

Now let's see your derivation. I can follow you until :
$$\tag{3}\psi(z):=\frac {\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)} =-\frac 1{z} -\gamma-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac 1{z+n}-\frac 1n\right]$$
After that (as explained by MPW) you can't remove the $\,\dfrac 1n\,$ parts since you would obtain divergent series. 
Let's continue the computations at this point (without expanding the $\psi(2z)$ part) :
\begin{align}
&f(z):=2\,\psi(2z)-\psi(z)-\psi\left(z+\frac 12\right)\\
&=2\,\psi(2z)+\frac 1{z}+\frac 1{z+1/2}+2\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac 1{z+n}+\frac 1{z+1/2+n}-\frac 2{n}\right]\\
&=2\,\left[\psi(2z)+\frac 1{2z}+\gamma+\frac 1{2z+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac 1{2z+2n}+\frac 1{2z+2n+1}-\frac 1{2n}-\frac 1{2n+1}+\\\frac 1{2n+1}-\frac 1{2n}\right]\right]\\
&=2\,\left[\psi(2z)+\frac 1{2z}+\gamma+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac 1{2z+m}-\frac 1m\right]+\frac 11+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac 1{2n+1}-\frac 1{2n}\right]\right]\\
&=2\,\left[\psi(2z)-\psi(2z)-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}m\right]\\
&=2\,\log(1+1)\\
\end{align}
(with $m$ combining the $2n$ and $2n+1$ terms)